# How to send binary data to interactive program using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I've an interactive program that prompts the user for input multiple times:

```
> Enter your input:
```

I want to supply binary data to the program at the Bash prompt, but I cannot find a method that works.

I've tried the following:

```
cat input.bin > /dev/pts/1
```

Here, `/dev/pts/1` is the program's tty.

This results in the binary data being displayed on the Bash prompt (encoded), instead of being send directly to the program. Pressing ENTER doesn't input the proper data.

I don't know how I should use copy-paste or environment variables to input binary data interactively?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered doing something like `cat input.bin | my_program.sh`?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim - this places all input in stdin, which doesn't work for interactive applications?

Comment: That's true. The terminal is not really the place for binary input. I don't think your problem is really solvable. The only other thing I can think of is to have the "Enter your input"  accept a filename rather than actual input.